# jsr-196 and single sign-on in glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-3, single-sign-on

I implemented a jsr-196 module for Glassfish. Now, if used, single sign-on isn't working anymore.

How to make sso work between different modules of my applications, some of which (but not all) use the jsr-196 module?

There isn't any error, but I don't get any SSO cookie (JSESSIONIDSSO for my other modules or apps). Also, if another module which doesn't use jsr-196 triggers sso, it isn't being used by the module which does use jsr-196.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more info before anyone will be able to help. What error are you seeing. How was jsr-196 implemented. etc....

Comment: No error at all, but no SSO cookie (JSESSIONIDSSO in my other projects). I had a quick look at the source and am thinking this is expected. But I guess there is a way of reusing GF valves to implement this, or some other solution.